# Android Activity Animations Timing

Tags: android, animation, responsive-design, android-annotations

I want to put some animations on my activities when they open and close.  But so far if i put them on it just makes it feel like the phone is lagging. And if I speed them up then you barely notice them.

What is the smallest time fragment which the average human can identify to? 50ms 100ms?

How can I make an animation noticeable, but not take away from the responsiveness of the application? Because obviously the animations them selves probably slow down the app allot.

Maybe Im asking a stupid question, If so I am sorry. But I thought that it is a fairly important aspect of designing a gpood app.

Comment: 1000ms would also do, and sometimes 1500ms

Comment: If you use the standard animation api, I think that the frame rate is set automatically based on available resources. That is, I think you should not bother about it. Anyway I use animations without real performance problems and test them on entry level phones, I never felt they are very heavy in terms of computation.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate says:

*"The human eye and its brain interface, the human visual system, can process 10 to 12 separate images per second, perceiving them individually."*

The 1896 standard movie frame rate was 16 fps. Today it is at least 24 fps.
I also remember the rate 18 events per second, not sure if it was MS-DOS or old TV.

The car driver's reaction time is estimated to be about 0.2 sec. (In the case that the driver is prepared to react.) This means that if something happens faster, a human has no time to move, despite of seeing it.

You can base your design on these digits.